# Target mobile devices with CSS (iPad, iPhone) but exclude non-mobile devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, css, media-queries

I'm trying to target mobile devices (specifically the iPad and iPhone) but using CSS3 media queries the same styling is added to other devices with the same resolution, such as laptops. How can I add mobile device specific styling without adding it to other non-mobile devices too?

So far I'm using this, which adds the css to all devices that are 1024px wide and under, even with the orientation selector:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (orientation:portrait),
                       (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape){
           // Do something
}
```

**EDIT:**
For anyone interested, I got this to work just by duplicating the media query but altering the duplicate slightly. It's by far the most efficient way of doing it but the main thing is it works:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (orientation:portrait),
                   (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape){
       // some styling
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (orientation:portrait),
                   (max-device-width: 768px) and (orientation:portrait){
       // some styling
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a look at [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html), at the section **"7.3 Recognized media types"**, will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this seems to work for landscape mode but portrait mode is ignored! Any ideas why this could be happening? I literally just swapped 'only screen' for 'only handheld' in the code above.

Comment: I see you edited your question and answered to yourself, but you could be interested in using min-width and max-width instead of min-device-width and max-device-width.

Comment: Yeah, your answer really helped! I'll give that a shot, sounds like I need to tidy the code up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Yup: [desktop browsers support the `orientation` media query too](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%40media_%28orientation%29).

I don’t think media queries provide a way to detect whether a device is the iPad or the iPhone. They allow you to inspect features of the device (like its width and orientation), rather than identify the device.

What makes your styles inappropriate for non-iPad devices?

Comment: Ahh, that'll be why! Unfortunately for me, the designer designed the site to be 1040px wide, so I just need to tweak the css

Comment: @mmmoustache: doh, that’s frustrating. I’d suggest just targeting the width then — users with browsers that support media queries who reduce the size of their browser window to below 1040 will also benefit from your tweaked styles.

Answer (score 0):

I found that all you need is the second media query in your edit:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (orientation: portrait),
   (max-device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {
   // some styling
}
```

It worked like a charm!